# Website setting when setting up an app in Facebook devleopers?

Tags: facebook

Is the website url setting just www.mysite.com, or is it the url to a server side script that deals with logging facebook users into your site?

[image]

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's your website domain name.

http://mzsms.my/#/login

[image]

Comment: Thanks Data. I'm having issues with some phones seeing a blank white screen when logging in via Facebook, yet others (same phone and os etc) are fine. Just eliminating possible defects in my set up.